# can't pass parameter correctly by "application/json"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I tried to find a workaround all morning(browsered every related post in SO & did several experiments myself), but failed.

Here's the Server code:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Test(Entity e)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string A { set; get; }

    public string B { set; get; }
}
```

With Client code:

```
var e = {
        A: "1",
        B: "2"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Test",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(e)
        //                data: e
    });
```

I get:
[image: notfine]

With Client Code:

```
var e = {
        A: "1",
        B: "2"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Test",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        //data: JSON.stringify(e)
        data: e
    });
```

I get:
[image: fine]

Hope to find a answer, coz application/json is more useful

**EDIT**

The parameters can be passed correctly when i change the protocal to **POST**.
Here's the new question: Why not **GET**?? coz the converted request querystring doesnt meet mvc3's need??

**EDIT2**

http://forums.asp.net/t/1766534.aspx/1

It seems that all issues are on the **GET** method. **GET** shouldn't pass complex params?? That's very weird if u are fan of restFUL

Comment: Nice you found a useful discussion on the difference between `Get` and `Post` request types. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the request type (although it defaults to GET anyway):

```
var e = {
            A: "1",
            B: "2"
        };

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/Test",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(e)
});
```

or, try using a `POST` request and decorate the `JsonResult` action method with the `[HttpPost]` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(Entity e)
{
     return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

then

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Test",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(e)
      });
```

Comment: OK, it works fine with "POST", BUT still doesnt work with "GET"...  WHY??